A loader for external ELF in ARM A53 FreeRTOS
I recently started working with embedded systems. I'm currently completing a project to implement a loader for external ELF files based on the Ultra96 V2 (ARM A53). The ARM A53 can receive ELF files transmitted externally (via TFTP), place them into a designated memory space (0x40000000), and then parse and load the ELF file. After loading and relocating, it can directly jump to the entry point using assembly and run.
Since the ELF file is transmitted externally, I used the -PIE option during compilation and linking but did not choose to dynamically link external libraries; in other words, the transmitted ELF file contains all the necessary libraries. I referred to https://github.com/erincandescent/elfload for my loading code. However, currently, after the external ELF file is loaded, it doesn't run properly. When I use Vitis to view the ASM code and debug, the program always shows an abnormal jump, and I can't print my output. I've tried modifying the entry point and the linker script but still have no results. Does anyone know what I might have not set correctly or overlooked? Thank you!
I tried modifying the linker script and adjusting the entry point of the external ELF file. I also attempted to add a simple piece of code to clear the .bss section and registers before the main function in the external ELF file, but each time an abnormal jump occurs during execution. I’m not sure if this issue is related to the device's MMU, as the virtual and physical addresses for this loader have always been the same.
here is my process about the loader right now:
https://github.com/yinbozhou/ELF-loader.git
you can generate the external elf file in the standalone folder in the standalone with this repository.
https://github.com/yinbozhou/Standalone.git
The following code shows my example main function and linker script for the external ELF file. I set the main function as the entry point, but in this case, xil_printf outputs nothing. However, myArray contains values as expected—I checked the memory addresses in vitis, and the values from 0 to 4 are correctly written. I'm uncertain if it's appropriate to use main directly as the entry point, as some initialization might be missing.
example main in standalone:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "platform_config.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"
int myArray[5];
int main()
{   
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        myArray[i]=i;
        xil_printf("number: %d\n", myArray[i]);
        }
    
    return 0;
    }

linker script:
/*******************************************************************/
/*                                                                 */
/* This file is automatically generated by linker script generator.*/
/*                                                                 */
/* Version: 2020.1                                                 */
/*                                                                 */
/* Copyright (c) 2010-2019 Xilinx, Inc.  All rights reserved.      */
/*                                                                 */
/* Description : ARM v8 Linker Script                           */
/*                                                                 */
/*******************************************************************/

_STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(_STACK_SIZE) ? _STACK_SIZE : 0xA000;
_HEAP_SIZE = DEFINED(_HEAP_SIZE) ? _HEAP_SIZE : 0xA000;

_EL0_STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(_EL0_STACK_SIZE) ? _EL0_STACK_SIZE : 1024;
_EL1_STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(_EL1_STACK_SIZE) ? _EL1_STACK_SIZE : 2048;
_EL2_STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(_EL2_STACK_SIZE) ? _EL2_STACK_SIZE : 1024;

/* Define Memories in the system */

MEMORY
{
   psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x7FF00000
   psu_ocm_ram_0_MEM_0 : ORIGIN = 0xFFFC0000, LENGTH = 0x40000
}

/* Specify the default entry point to the program */

ENTRY(main)

/* Define the sections, and where they are mapped in memory */

PHDRS
{
  text PT_LOAD FLAGS(5);    /* Readable and executable */
  data PT_LOAD FLAGS(7);    /* Readable, writable, executable */
  dynamic PT_DYNAMIC; 
}

SECTIONS
{
.text : {
   KEEP (*(.vectors))
   *(.boot)
   *(.text)
   *(.text.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
   *(.plt)
   *(.gnu_warning)
   *(.gcc_execpt_table)
   *(.glue_7)
   *(.glue_7t)
   *(.ARM.extab)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.init (ALIGN(64)) : {
   KEEP (*(.init))
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.fini (ALIGN(64)) : {
   KEEP (*(.fini))
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.interp : {
   KEEP (*(.interp))
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.note-ABI-tag : {
   KEEP (*(.note-ABI-tag))
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.rodata : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __rodata_start = .;
   *(.rodata)
   *(.rodata.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
   __rodata_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.rodata1 : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __rodata1_start = .;
   *(.rodata1)
   *(.rodata1.*)
   __rodata1_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.sdata2 : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __sdata2_start = .;
   *(.sdata2)
   *(.sdata2.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.s2.*)
   __sdata2_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.sbss2 : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __sbss2_start = .;
   *(.sbss2)
   *(.sbss2.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.sb2.*)
   __sbss2_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.data : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __data_start = .;
   *(.data)
   *(.data.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
   *(.jcr)
   *(.got)
   *(.got.plt)
   __data_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.dynamic : {
   *(.dynamic)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.dynsym : {
   *(.dynsym)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.dynstr : {
   *(.dynstr)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.rela.dyn : {
   *(.rela.dyn)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.plt : {
   *(.plt)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.data1 : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __data1_start = .;
   *(.data1)
   *(.data1.*)
   __data1_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.got : {
   *(.got)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.got1 : {
   *(.got1)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.got2 : {
   *(.got2)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.note.gnu.build-id : {
   KEEP (*(.note.gnu.build-id))
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :text

.ctors : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __CTOR_LIST__ = .;
   ___CTORS_LIST___ = .;
   KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
   KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend.o) .ctors))
   KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
   KEEP (*(.ctors))
   __CTOR_END__ = .;
   ___CTORS_END___ = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.dtors : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __DTOR_LIST__ = .;
   ___DTORS_LIST___ = .;
   KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
   KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend.o) .dtors))
   KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
   KEEP (*(.dtors))
   __DTOR_END__ = .;
   ___DTORS_END___ = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.fixup : {
   __fixup_start = .;
   *(.fixup)
   __fixup_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.eh_frame : {
   *(.eh_frame)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.eh_framehdr : {
   __eh_framehdr_start = .;
   *(.eh_framehdr)
   __eh_framehdr_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.gcc_except_table : {
   *(.gcc_except_table)
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.mmu_tbl0 (ALIGN(4096)) : {
   __mmu_tbl0_start = .;
   *(.mmu_tbl0)
   __mmu_tbl0_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.mmu_tbl1 (ALIGN(4096)) : {
   __mmu_tbl1_start = .;
   *(.mmu_tbl1)
   __mmu_tbl1_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.mmu_tbl2 (ALIGN(4096)) : {
   __mmu_tbl2_start = .;
   *(.mmu_tbl2)
   __mmu_tbl2_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.ARM.exidx : {
   __exidx_start = .;
   *(.ARM.exidx*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.armexidix.*.*)
   __exidx_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.preinit_array : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __preinit_array_start = .;
   KEEP (*(SORT(.preinit_array.*)))
   KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
   __preinit_array_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.init_array : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __init_array_start = .;
   KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
   KEEP (*(.init_array))
   __init_array_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.fini_array : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __fini_array_start = .;
   KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
   KEEP (*(.fini_array))
   __fini_array_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.ARM.attributes : {
   __ARM.attributes_start = .;
   *(.ARM.attributes)
   __ARM.attributes_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.sdata : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __sdata_start = .;
   *(.sdata)
   *(.sdata.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.s.*)
   __sdata_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.sbss (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __sbss_start = .;
   *(.sbss)
   *(.sbss.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __sbss_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.tdata : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __tdata_start = .;
   *(.tdata)
   *(.tdata.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   __tdata_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.tbss : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __tbss_start = .;
   *(.tbss)
   *(.tbss.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
   __tbss_end = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.bss (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __bss_start__ = .;
   *(.bss)
   *(.bss.*)
   *(.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __bss_end__ = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

_SDA_BASE_ = __sdata_start + ((__sbss_end - __sdata_start) / 2 );

_SDA2_BASE_ = __sdata2_start + ((__sbss2_end - __sdata2_start) / 2 );

/* Generate Stack and Heap definitions */

.heap (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   _heap = .;
   HeapBase = .;
   _heap_start = .;
   . += _HEAP_SIZE;
   _heap_end = .;
   HeapLimit = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

.stack (NOLOAD) : {
   . = ALIGN(64);
   _el3_stack_end = .;
   . += _STACK_SIZE;
   __el3_stack = .;
   _el2_stack_end = .;
   . += _EL2_STACK_SIZE;
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __el2_stack = .;
   _el1_stack_end = .;
   . += _EL1_STACK_SIZE;
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __el1_stack = .;
   _el0_stack_end = .;
   . += _EL0_STACK_SIZE;
   . = ALIGN(64);
   __el0_stack = .;
} > psu_ddr_0_MEM_0 :data

_end = .;
}

The following code demonstrates my ELF loading task and part of the memory allocation function that I modified based on content from GitHub (as FreeRTOS operates as a bare-metal-like system). The basic steps involve parsing the ELF file, which has been stored at memory address 0x40000000, loading each section to its allocated address, and performing relocation. After completing these steps, I use two lines of assembly code to jump to the starting point of the memory allocated for loading (currently 0x210008). I'm sorry I can't provide the full code as it is too lengthy to display in its entirety.
int aligned_malloc(void** ptr, size_t alignment, size_t size) {
    if (ptr == NULL) return 1; // error if the pointer is null
    void* p = pvPortMalloc(size + alignment - 1 + sizeof(void*));
    if (p == NULL) {
        xil_printf("Error: Memory allocation failed in aligned_malloc\n");
        return 1;
    } 
    xil_printf("Allocated memory at base address: %p\n", p);
    // adjust the pointer and make sure the align
    size_t offset = (size_t)p % alignment;
     xil_printf("Origin Alignment offset: %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long)offset);
    if (offset != 0) {
        offset = alignment - offset;
    }
    xil_printf("Alignment offset: 0x%x bytes\n", (unsigned long)offset);
    void* aligned_ptr = (void*)((size_t)p + offset + sizeof(void*));
    xil_printf("Aligned memory address: %p\n", aligned_ptr);
    
    *((void**)((size_t)aligned_ptr - sizeof(void*))) = p;

    *ptr = aligned_ptr; 
    xil_printf("Memory address returned to user: %p\n", *ptr);
    return 0; 
}

void ELFLoaderTask(void *p){
    int receivedmessage;
    xQueueReceive(xQueue, &receivedmessage, portMAX_DELAY);

    void *buf;

    ctx.pread = fpread;

    check(el_init(&ctx), "initialising");
    
    if (aligned_malloc(&buf, ctx.align, ctx.memsz)) {
        xil_printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        vTaskDelete(NULL);
        return;
    }
    xil_printf("aligned_malloc is executed successfully, buf=%p\n", buf);

    ctx.base_load_vaddr = ctx.base_load_paddr = (uintptr_t) buf;
    
    check(el_load(&ctx, alloccb), "loading");
   
    check(el_relocate(&ctx), "relocating");
 
    uintptr_t epaddr = (uintptr_t)ctx.ehdr.e_entry()+ (uintptr_t) buf;
  
    entrypoint_t ep = (entrypoint_t)epaddr;

    xil_printf("Binary entrypoint is %" PRIxPTR "; invoking %p\n", (uintptr_t) ctx.ehdr.e_entry, ep);

    jump_to_entry((uintptr_t)epaddr);

    aligned_free(buf);
    
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
    
}

